# Python.. Accessing the default sort function?

Tags: python, list, sorting

Python Code:

```
b=['six', 'small', 'he', 'foxes', 'saw']
b.sort(key=len)
b
```

Output:

```
['he', 'six', 'saw', 'small', 'foxes']
```

In the above code, I sorted by length of elements and got the above output.

The output I want looks like this: ['he', 'saw', 'six', 'small', 'foxes']

So I want the first sort by length. Then for elements with the same length I want to sort alphabetically.

My question: Is there a way to do it without writing a custom function? Maybe something like this:

```
b.sort(key=[len,sorted]) # this doesn't work but I think it explains the idea.
```

Thanks!

Comment: `Then for elements with the same length I want to sort alphabetically.`  -- Does this mena it should be  `['he', 'saw', 'six', 'foxes', 'small']`

Comment: The described order should be: `['he', 'saw', 'six', 'foxes', 'small']`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We can use a compound sorting key, first sort by length, second lexicographically. We do this by creating a tuple, because tuples will naturally sort using the elements in the order they appear.

```
b = ['six', 'small', 'he', 'foxes', 'saw']
b.sort(key=lambda s: (len(s), s))
```

For the record, the above results in this sorted list::

```
['he', 'saw', 'six', 'foxes', 'small']
```

Which is the correct order as stipulated in the question (but the sample output in the question is wrong, so please be aware of it before downvoting!)

Comment: Guys, the order in my answer _is_ correct. What's incorrect is the expected output in the question! `['he', 'saw', 'six', 'foxes', 'small']` is the described order

Comment: i recommend you to add description to your answer, about the output

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Never downvoted your question, just commented. After that I have checked again the question to be sure, and edited the question, after that removed the useless comment and upvoted.

Comment: You are right... I was just focused on 'saw' & 'six' .. thanks

Answer (score 2):

An easy option is to sort twice:

```
b.sort()
b.sort(key=len)
```

Because sort is *stable*, it keeps the order of elements in case that they are equal according to the key; so by sorting alphabetically first, the items with equal length stay sorted that way.